# Pushing Data From Viewcontroller to NavigationController, which both under tabbarcontroller

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I m creating an apps, that has tabbarcontroller, navigation controller and viewcontroller
storyboard is like this

### Tabbarcontroller

- 1 viewController(ScanViewController)
- 2 NavigationController1 - UITableviewController (SalesOrder)
- 3 NavigationController2 - UITableviewController
- 4 NavigationController3

right now, I can pass some data from a rootviewcontroller of navigationcontroller1 to the view controller by code like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ScanViewController *svc =[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    svc.company_name.text= cell.textLabel.text;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

}
```

however, I cant pass data from viewController to any rootviewcontroller of navigationcontroller
my code like this

```
-(IBAction)button_order{
    SalesOrder *so =[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    so.sales_order_list_from_scan = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"SO 4",@"SO 5",nil];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

could you tell me anything wrong here? I checked my self, seems SalesOrder(UITableview, RootViewController of NavigationController1) so was not initialized.
if I add item in SalesOrder.m, it works, so I dont think it s any delegate problem.
the problem was something wrong with

```
[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

thank you